# MongoDB - Invalid Operator - Agregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I have the following aggregation and I receive the error invalid operator $$event.info.

```
db.days.aggregate([
    { 
        $match : { 'day' : 'March_1'}
    },
    {
        $project: 
        {
            _id:0,
            day: 1,
            events:
            {
               $filter:
               {
                    input: '$events',
                    as: 'event',
                    cond: 
                    {
                        $and: 
                        [
                            {
                                $eq: ['$$event.year', '2002']
                            },
                            {
                                '$$event.info' : {$regex: '.*peseta.*'}
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
    }
])
```

Event is an array with objects of type

```
{
    year : "x"
    info : "y"
}
```

Could you please help me some an explanation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't use `$regex` in `$project`

Comment: Is there any workaround to be able to use a $regex like function in $project?

Comment: As stated, there is no "logical" counterpart for a `$regex` expression. In your case here you should need to `$unwind` the array and then `$match` with a regular query expression afterwards. I also strongly advise that you include the same condition in your initial `$match` as well. Otherwise you are just selecting documents where array elements cannot possibly match the conditions. Unless of course you intend to return possible "empty" arrays as well.

Answer (score -1):

What is your expected output.
If you just want to match you don't require aggregation framework for it.just use find
 
`db.days.find({'day' : 'March_1',event :{$elemMatch :{'year', '2002',info' : {$regex: '.*peseta.*'}}})`

Comment: Why this has been rated negative please correct me if i am wrong